# Angular using wrapper component for primeng p-inputnumber not able to style

Tags: primeng, angular11

I am new to PrimeNg with Angular. I have a simple primeng p-inputnumber component as below:

```
<p-inputNumber   
    [showButtons]="true"
    [placeholder]="placeholderText"
    incrementButtonIcon="fal fa-plus"
    decrementButtonIcon="fal fa-minus"
    [minFractionDigits]="_config?.integer ? 0 : 1"   
    [min]="_config?.minValue"
    [max]="_config?.maxValue"
    [(ngModel)]="value"
    (onBlur)="onBlur()"> 
</p-inputNumber>
```

And have created a wrapper to this component i.e  is the wrapper to the above component and using it in a homepage component. Now i want to apply style to this wrapper component which in turn should apply style to primeng component. Right now it is not setting.

```
Homepagecomponent.html
---<app-number-input class="disabled">
------<p-inputNumber>
```

i set the below style in homepagecomponent.scss

```
:host ::ng-deep .disabled {
    background: red;
}
```

But the above is not being set. Can anyone help me how to achieve my expected?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need something like this in your CSS

```
:host ::ng-deep {
    // you may want to specify your app element or something here to be more specific than just .disabled class
    .disabled {
        // tweak this list to whichever pieces of the p-inputnumber you want to have red background
        .p-inputnumber, 
        .p-inputnumber-stacked, 
        .p-inputnumber-horizontal, 
        .p-inputnumber-vertical, 
        .p-inputnumber-input, 
        .p-inputnumber-button, 
        .p-inputnumber-button-up, 
        .p-inputnumber-button-down, 
        .p-inputnumber-button-icon {
            background-color: red;
        }
    }
}
```